# Unable to install the application in Teams due to Policy Issue from Teams Admin Panel

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams

I have an application called Beep. The Application was successfully published in the Teams app store last year.

Beep consists of a message extension, bot and personal tab.

Recently we have been facing an issue with the app installation:

When the tenant admin adds the Beep to a team from the MS Teams Admin Panel, the app doesn’t hit our server, though we have this below code which should be executed first:

```
constructor() {

     super();

     this.onConversationUpdate(async (handler) => { 

          console.log('over here'); // <------ nothing happens here on adding the app.

     }

}
```

Important Note: This above ONLY happens in the tenants who have their policy as below. For the rest, it works fine as expected.

[image: e]

Comment: well, you obviously need permision, as for what to do to remove it, for what i know unless they give you administration rights you will be unable to install extensions that your company doesn´t allow. (it sucks, i also miss a few plugins)

Comment: I am the admin of the team and I want if users wish to install this app they could.

Comment: If you're a global admin, you can review, and grant consent to apps that request permissions on behalf of all users in your organization.

To grant org-wide consent to an app, follow these steps mentioned in document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/app-permissions-admin-center#grant-org-wide-admin-consent-to-an-app

Answer (score 0):

If you're a global admin, you can review, and grant consent to apps that request permissions on behalf of all users in your organization.

To grant org-wide consent to an app, follow these steps:

1. In the left navigation of the Microsoft Teams admin center, go to Teams apps > Manage apps.
2. Do one of the following:

   Search for the app you want, select the app name to go to the app details page, and then select the Permissions tab.

   Sort the Permissions column in descending order to find the app, and then select View details. Doing this takes you to the Permissions tab of the app details page.
3. Under Org-wide permissions, select Review permissions and consent.

[image: Screenshot of org-wide permissions on the Permissions tab for an app.]

You must be a global admin to do this. This option isn't available to Teams service admins.

4. On the Permissions tab, review the permissions requested by the app.

[image]

5. If you agree with the permissions requested by the app, select Accept to grant consent. A banner temporarily appears at the top of the page to let you know that the requested permissions have been granted for the app. The app now has access to the specified resources for all users in your organization and no one else will be prompted to review the permissions.

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/app-permissions-admin-center#grant-org-wide-admin-consent-to-an-app